# How to use neon intrinsic on eclipse CDT?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, neon

I am using arm neon intrinsic in my c project on eclipse CDT.

But it always show some "Type XXX could not be resolved" error even when I included **arm_neon.h** as the library.

eg:
 Type 'uint8x8_t' could not be resolved.

Type 'uint8x16x4_t' could not be resolved...

The project can be build fine when using ndk-build. And I have already included the path of 
**arm_neon.h** in "Paths and Symbols".

What can I do then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by using jni in android project.

I can't find any way to pass this error in pure C.(Maybe some one can find out??)

I new an android project and make jni call in this project.

Then writing all my C code in the jni and build it by ndk.

This is the only solution I found.